# C# - Запрет преобразования из интерфейса

Tags: c#, ооп, интерфейс

Возникла необходимость в разделении класса на уровни доступа. В принципах SOLID это называется [принципом разделения интерфейсов](https://professorweb.ru/my/it/blog/net/solid.php) (ISP).

Например, есть класс `Record`, который реализует интерфейсы `IReadable` и `IWritable`:

```
interface IReadable
{
    string ReadValue();
}

interface IWritable
{
    void WriteValue(string value);
}

class Record : IReadable, IWritable
{
    private string _value;

    public Record(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public string ReadValue()
    {
        return _value;
    }

    public void WriteValue(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Допустим, одному клиенту дается экземпляр этого класса под интерфейсом `IReadable`, а другому клиенту под `IWritable`:

```
Record record = new("some value");

IReadable readableRecord = record; // передается клиенту #1
IWritable writableRecord = record; // передается клиенту #2
```

Но может возникнуть ситуация, когда один из клиентов может "взломать" эти уровни доступа преобразованием интерфейса в исходный класс, и исключение при этом не появляется:

```
IReadable readableRecord = record;
Record record = (Record)readableRecord; // исключение не появляется

record.WriteValue("new value");
Console.WriteLine(readableRecord.ReadValue()); // new value
```

Данное решение выглядит простым в реализации и не требует создания классов-обёрток для распределения уровней доступа, но действует оно, грубо говоря, "на словах".
Можно ли запретить такое преобразование типов? Если нет, то каким способом можно реализовать такой функционал?

Comment: Сделать класс объекта доступным для создания из фабрики, чтобы он был internal

Comment: Особого смысла запрещать нет, так как все это делается для удобства программистов и снижения вероятности ошибок. Если же программист сознательно хочет выстрелить себе в ногу как в этом примере - тут ничем не поможешь.